# Add row to class diagram

Tags: draw.io

I am making a class diagram in draw.io, but I am completly new at it.

I am using the UML>Class2 figure.

The first three properties are part of the figure, but how do you get row number 4?

I assume there must be something so the text gets attached to the current figures.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Select one of the existing rows and duplicate (ctrl/cmd-d or right click, select duplicate).

Comment: What do I do if there are no existing rows? Do I always have to keep at least one row around?

Comment: By copy pasting it the new cell won't align properly and you must move it around in order to place it correctly. As suggested below Ctrl+Enter is the way to go.

Answer (score 90):

If you want to add a new row below the selected one use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

It's better solution if you are dealing with classes with method and attribute fields. (Ex.: Class figure)

Answer (score 16):

If you have deleted all of the rows from the class diagram:

[image]

Then you will have to make a new class diagram and drag one of the fields into the old one:

[image]

Resulting in:

[image]

Then to add further cells you can follow the other answers.

Answer (score 13):

[As @Amadeusz and @RyanZim said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815539/8951829), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a proper way to add a new row **ON Windows**.

**ON macOS**, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd> to do that.